# RecyclerView with a partial swipe row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

I would like to achieve something like the image below.

[image: RecyclerView Swipe Row]

But I don't have any idea how to do it.

Notice that the ***Menu Burger***, must implement a click that perform automatically the swipe.

Furthermore, I would like that the items (the *Checkmark*, the *Pen* and the *Cross*) can be clickable.

> **Note:** I prefer if it's a solution with a ***RecyclerView***

Any advices, suggestions or libraries are welcomed.

Comment: Check up this. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html